# Windows Phone 8.1 LongListSelector does not automatically update on data refresh

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, longlistselector

I have a simple LongListSelector displaying some data. When I modify a record, the LongListSelector does not display the changes. I want that, when a record changes, the LongListSelector automatically displays the changes.
How can I do that? Is there a way to force my LongListSelector to display updated data?

EDIT:

Data are stored in an ObservableCollection and added to the LongListSelector using DataContext.

Comment: How are you setting data in LongListSelector? Are you using binding? Are you using ObservableCollection? Do your classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged? More information is needed to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: Searching over the network I've read about the INotifyPropertyChanged, but I don't clearly understand what is and how to use it. Please, can you explain me what I have to do to to implement autoupdate on my LongListSelector?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231552/windows-phone-8-1-longlistselector-issues-in-data-updates) is what I'm actually doing to display updated data on my LongListSelector

Comment: The best way for updating the view/controls is MVVM pattern. in your example you are not implementing this pattern. In MVVM when every data source is changed the view is updated automatically this is what you want to do in your longlist selector. My suggestion is to Use MVVM Light(http://www.mvvmlight.net/) it is simple to use you can also download it using nuget. I will post example how I am using it in my projects.

Comment: @top_broker Maybe taking a look at this is useful: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-18-Understanding-MVVM-ObservableCollection-T-and-INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), I understand MVVM Pattern and solve my problem.
In my case, my Model did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so the Model did not notify the View about changes. In order to sync View and Model:

- Model must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so that PropertyChangedEventArgs() event can be raised when some properties has changed.
- The collection (data) must be an ObservableCollection.
- Finally, use binding to sync Model and View.